# Model with DB table insert , update

Tags: php, zend-framework, architecture

I have such model for my company with have method setOptions for creating object from array or Zend_DB_Table_Row

```
<?php

class Model_Company 
{
    protected $c_id;
    protected $c_shortname;
    protected $c_longname;


    public function __constructor(array $options = null)
    {
        if(is_array($options)) {
            $this->setOptions($options);
        }
    }

    public function setOptions($data)
    {
        if($data instanceof Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract) {
            $data = $data->toArray();
        }
        if(is_object($data)) {
            $data = (array)$data;
        }
        if(!is_array($data)) {
            throw new Exception('Initial data must be object or array');
        }
        $methods = get_class_methods($this);
        foreach($data as $key => $value) {
            $method = 'set'.ucfirst($key);
            if(in_array($method, $methods)) {
                $this->{'c_'.$key} = $value;    
            }

        }
        return $this;
    }
```

I also have company manager with param like model and adapter for different db/soap/rest

```
  class Model_CompanyManager 
{
    private $_adapter;
    public function __construct(Model_Company $model,$adapter) 
    {
        $this->_adapter = $adapter;
        $this->_model = $model;
        return $this;
    }   
    /**
     * Save data
     * @var Model_Company $data
     */
    public function save(array $data)
    {
        $data = $this->_model->setOptions($data);
        $this->_adapter->save($data);
    }


}
```

And DBTable in DBTable

```
class Model_DbTable_Company extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'company';
    protected $_id = 'c_id';


    public function save(Model_Company $data) 
    {

        try {
            if(isset($data['c_id'])) {
                $this->update($data, 'c_id = :c_id',array('c_id' => $data['c_id']));
            } else {

                $this->insert($data);

            }    
        } catch (Zend_Db_Exception $e) {
            throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
        }
    }


}
```

How can I insert into db because model properties are protected and I can't do (array)$data

```
$this->_companyManager = new Model_CompanyManager(new Model_Company,new Model_DbTable_Company);
$this->_companyManager->save($values);
```

I don't what to create array with fields name inside save like this:

```
$data = array(
            'c_shortname' => $company->getShortname(),
            'c_longname' => $company->getLongName(),
            'c_description' => $company->getDescription(),
            'c_salt' => $company->getSalt(),
            'c_password' => $company->getPassword(),
            'c_updated_at' => date('YmdHis')
        );
```

Because when I gonna change model fields names and other stuff I have to remember also to change here... Is there is simple approach , pattern that model keep everything and it clean

Comment: When you call `$this->_companyManager->save($values);` you are actually calling `Model_DbTable_Company::save()` with `$values`. What is `$values`? `Model_DbTable_Company::save()` expects a `Model_Company` as parameter.

Comment: Static function are difficult to test so this approach is wrong. When I saving values there Model_Company object

Comment: `::` does not mean static. For static you must use the keyword `static`. It's the syntax to describe a method with its class and so to differentiate from `Model_CompanyManager::save()`

Answer (score 2):

If you simply want to get a list of all your objects properties with reflection you could use [get_class_vars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-vars.php).  With a recent version of PHP this will return all the class variables regardless of scope.  But since you are tossing in this *Manager*, usually called a [Data Mapper](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html), I assume you expect your model objects will not align exactly to a database table.  Otherwise you should just stick to the table-row-gateway pattern of the Zend_Db_Table classes.

I personally am a big fan of the Data Mapper pattern in conjunction with ZF applications.  Only the most simple apps are going to line up to relational database tables.  It encourages richer objects and writing models and business logic before database schemas.

The job of the mapper is exactly what it suggests, to map your entity to a persistence layer, so handling in the mappers save() method, the actual assignments for the SQL statement (probably building an array with your tables field names and assigning the values, maybe even saving to multiple tables) is perfectly acceptable.

If some of your objects are more simple and do align better with a table, as will certainly be the case, what I like to do is have a __toArray() method for the object.  It can be responsible for returning a representation suitable for building an insert/update statement.  Also useful for needing a JSON representation for serving it via AJAX.  You can be as lazy as you like in writing these - use that get_class_vars function or other reflection.  I usually have two mapper base classes.  One with CRUD functions that essentially do what Zend_Db_Table does, and another more skeletal where I am responsible for writing more of the code.  They should follow a common interface.  Kinda gets you the best of both worlds.

I found [this link](http://survivethedeepend.com/zendframeworkbook/en/1.0/implementing.the.domain.model.entries.and.authors#zfbook.implementing.the.domain.model.entries.and.authors.implementation.the.data.mappers) to be a good resource for some ideas.

Comment: Thx for link ... My problem is one you have method __toArray to change Object to array... If I don't want to change in both places Model and Mapping class I will user get_class_vars. Do you think is right approach and should be done like this or created array with all elements...

Comment: What do you mean by both in the Model and Mapping class?  I was suggesting the `__toArray` method on the model, probably being called by the mapper.  That mapper would need to know how to take the SQL result and build the object, and inversely covert the object into something suitable for insert/update.  What is it you want to avoid having to do?  One thing I can suggest is to start writing some code.  Do a couple objects and their mappers.  Then go back and re-factor to eliminate what you start to see as being the 'common' code.  If you can elaborate a bit more I can try and answer better.